# Limit the number of transaction per seconds on HTTP persistent connection Using Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, java-ee-6, embedded-jetty, jetty-8

I want to know the approaches to configure Jetty to limit number of transaction that can happen in Single HTTP persistent connection. Which class do we need to extend to that make this configurable?

Suppose my client application request lands on my jetty server with HTTP persistent connection then only 500 transaction I want to allow to this connection and after that we need to force client application to re-establish this connection because their limit is over.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the QoSFilter, while it likely does not do specifically what you are looking for it represents the spirit and may be able to be adapted to your needs.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/qos-filter.html

If you were to update it for your specific use case I would encourage you to contribute it back to the project.